# relação de tabelas no banco de dados

Tags: mysql

Preciso fazer duas tabelas de produtos conversarem entre si no MySql, sendo elas `produto` (pai) X `insumo` (filha).

Exemplo:

> PRODUTO: ALMOÇO BISTECA
>   INSUMOS QUE COMPÕEM O PRATO:
>            arroz;
>            feijão;
>            bisteca;
>            farinha

Preciso para que quando eu for colocar a relação de custo dos insumos, eu já consiga tirar o custo final do prato. Além disso, os insumos precisam ficar numa tabela separada pois há diversos outros insumos que compõem outros pratos.

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual. Pedidos de refatoração completa ou código pronto, tutoriais e/ou coisas que envolvem mais de um assunto no mesmo post geralmente não se encaixam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Se tem dúvida em algum detalhe específico, reduzir o código a um [MCVE] pode ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta é um tanto extensa.

Preparei um script de criação de tabelas que deve te dar um norte para sua solução:

```
-- Tabela de Produtos
CREATE TABLE PRODUTO
(
    COD_PRODUTO INT,
    TXT_DESCRICAO VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(COD_PRODUTO)
)

-- TABELA DE INSUMOS
CREATE TABLE INSUMO
(
   COD_INSUMO INT,
   TXT_DESCRICAO varchar(50),
   PRIMARY KEY(COD_INSUMO)
)   

-- TABELA QUE RELACIONA PRODUTOS E INSUMOS
CREATE TABLE PRODUTO_INSUMO
(
   COD_PRODUTO_INSUMO INT,
   COD_PRODUTO INT,
   COD_INSUMO INT,
   NUM_QUANTIDADE INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (COD_PRODUTO_INSUMO)
)

-- RELACIONAMENTOS 
ALTER TABLE PRODUTO_INSUMO
  ADD CONSTRAINT
      FOREIGN KEY (COD_PRODUTO)
      REFERENCES PRODUTO(COD_PRODUTO)

ALTER TABLE PRODUTO_INSUMO
  ADD CONSTRAINT
      FOREIGN KEY (COD_INSUMO)
      REFERENCES INSUMO(COD_INSUMO)
```

Scripts que exemplificam a informação conforme sua especificação:

```
-- INSUMO:
INSERT INTO INSUMO (COD_INSUMO, TXT_DESCRICAO) VALUES (1, 'FEIJAO')
INSERT INTO INSUMO (COD_INSUMO, TXT_DESCRICAO) VALUES (2, 'ARROZ')
INSERT INTO INSUMO (COD_INSUMO, TXT_DESCRICAO) VALUES (3, 'FARINHA DE MANDIOCA')
INSERT INTO INSUMO (COD_INSUMO, TXT_DESCRICAO) VALUES (4, 'CARNE')   

-- PRODUTO:
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (COD_PRODUTO,TXT_DESCRICAO) VALUES (1, 'FEIJOADA')
INSERT INTO PRODUTO (COD_PRODUTO,TXT_DESCRICAO) VALUES (2, 'BIFE A MILANESA')

-- PRODUTO_INSUMO:

-- 1 KG DE FEIJAO NA FEIJOADA
   INSERT INTO PRODUTO_INSUMO (COD_PRODUTO, COD_INSUMO, NUM_QUANTIDADE) 
   VALUES (1,1,1) 

-- 1 KG DE ARROZ NA FEIJOADA
   INSERT INTO PRODUTO_INSUMO (COD_PRODUTO, COD_INSUMO, NUM_QUANTIDADE) 
   VALUES (1,2,1) 

-- 2 KG DE FARINHA DE MANDIOCA NA FEIJOADA
   INSERT INTO PRODUTO_INSUMO (COD_PRODUTO, COD_INSUMO, NUM_QUANTIDADE) 
   VALUES (1,3,2) 

-- 3KG CARNE NO BIFE A MILANESA
   INSERT INTO PRODUTO_INSUMO (COD_PRODUTO, COD_INSUMO, NUM_QUANTIDADE) 
   VALUES (2,4,3) 

-- 1 KG FARINHA DE MANDIOCA NO BIFE
   INSERT INTO PRODUTO_INSUMO (COD_PRODUTO, COD_INSUMO,NUM_QUANTIDADE) 
   VALUES (2,3,1)
```

Espero que ajude.